# Plotting a non linear best fit line in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, regression, best-fit-curve, best-fit

I'm trying to plot a best fit line for my train/test dataset and compare with the original values to see how well it fits.

I am able to plot the [line of fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2v1bn.png) for the original dataset. But when it comes to the train/test dataset, it goes [haywire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfndP.png). Appreciate any inputs on this.

```
# Importing the dataset
dataset = 
pd.read_excel('experimental_data.xlsx', 
sheet_name = 'Sheet1')
x = dataset['λ'].values
y = dataset['P'].values

df = pd.DataFrame(dataset[["λ", "P"]])    

#Training the dataset
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = 
train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.3, 
random_state = 1)

regressor = 
RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 10, 
random_state = 1)
regressor.fit(X_train.reshape(-1,1), 
y_train.reshape(-1,1))

y_pred = 
regressor.predict(X_test.reshape(-1,1))
x_pred = 
regressor.predict(y_test.reshape(-1,1))

RanDF = pd.DataFrame({'Real Values of P 
[MPa]':y_test.reshape(-1), 
               'Predicted Values of P 
[MPa]':y_pred.reshape(-1)})
RandF = RanDF.sort_values(by='Real Values of 
P [MPa]')


# Plotting the graph
plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))

X_grid = np.arange(min(x), max(x), 0.01)
X_grid = X_grid.reshape((len(X_grid), 1))

plt.plot(x, y,'r', linestyle = ':', lw = 
1.5, zorder = 1,)
plt.scatter(x = "λ", y = "P", data = df, 
linestyle = 'dashed', marker = 'o', s = 0, 
color = 'indigo', zorder = 2)

 plt.plot(X_test, y_pred,'b', linestyle = 
 ':', lw = 1.5, zorder = 3)
plt.scatter(x = "λ", y = "P", data = df, 
linestyle = 'dashed', marker = 'o', s = 0, 
color = 'indigo', zorder = 4)

RealVRand = plt.scatter(X_test, y_test, 
color = 'forestgreen', s=40, zorder=5)
PredVRand = plt.scatter(X_test, y_pred, 
color = 'darkorchid', s=40, zorder=6)

plt.title('Random Forest Regression', 
fontsize = 15)
plt.xlabel('λ', fontsize = 14)
plt.ylabel('P [MPa]', fontsize = 14)
plt.legend ((RealVRand, PredVRand), 
('Actual', 'Predicted'), scatterpoints = 1, 
loc='upper left', ncol = 40, fontsize = 12)

plt.show()
```

### Data

[dataset](https://entuedu-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/echang009_e_ntu_edu_sg/EYjb4EbVv21JmI1bYeZ4PYwBaghH4EPis2JoQVVvhJ93UA?e=BlM4ZJ)

```
λ   P
1.00    0.00
1.02    0.03
1.04    0.07
1.06    0.10
1.08    0.13
1.10    0.16
1.12    0.18
1.14    0.21
1.16    0.24
1.18    0.26
1.20    0.29
1.22    0.31
1.24    0.33
1.26    0.36
1.28    0.38
1.30    0.40
1.32    0.42
1.34    0.44
1.36    0.46
1.38    0.48
1.40    0.50
1.42    0.52
1.44    0.54
1.46    0.56
1.48    0.58
1.50    0.60
1.52    0.62
1.54    0.63
1.56    0.65
1.58    0.67
1.60    0.69
1.62    0.70
1.64    0.72
1.66    0.74
1.68    0.75
1.70    0.77
1.72    0.78
1.74    0.80
1.76    0.82
1.78    0.83
1.80    0.85
1.82    0.86
1.84    0.88
1.86    0.89
1.88    0.91
1.90    0.92
1.92    0.94
1.94    0.95
1.96    0.96
1.98    0.98
2.00    0.99
2.02    1.01
2.04    1.02
2.06    1.03
2.08    1.05
2.10    1.06
2.12    1.08
2.14    1.09
2.16    1.10
2.18    1.12
2.20    1.13
2.22    1.14
2.24    1.16
2.26    1.17
2.28    1.18
2.30    1.20
2.32    1.21
2.34    1.22
2.36    1.24
2.38    1.25
2.40    1.26
2.42    1.28
2.44    1.29
2.46    1.30
2.48    1.31
2.50    1.33
2.52    1.34
2.54    1.35
2.56    1.37
2.58    1.38
2.60    1.39
2.62    1.40
2.64    1.42
2.66    1.43
2.68    1.44
2.70    1.45
2.72    1.47
2.74    1.48
2.76    1.49
2.78    1.50
2.80    1.52
2.82    1.53
2.84    1.54
2.86    1.55
2.88    1.57
2.90    1.58
2.92    1.59
2.94    1.60
2.96    1.61
2.98    1.63
3.00    1.64
3.02    1.65
3.04    1.66
3.06    1.68
3.08    1.69
3.10    1.70
3.12    1.71
3.14    1.72
3.16    1.74
3.18    1.75
3.20    1.76
3.22    1.77
3.24    1.78
3.26    1.80
3.28    1.81
3.30    1.82
3.32    1.83
3.34    1.84
3.36    1.86
3.38    1.87
3.40    1.88
3.42    1.89
3.44    1.90
3.46    1.92
3.48    1.93
3.50    1.94
3.52    1.95
3.54    1.96
3.56    1.97
3.58    1.99
3.60    2.00
3.62    2.01
3.64    2.02
3.66    2.03
3.68    2.05
3.70    2.06
3.72    2.07
3.74    2.08
3.76    2.09
3.78    2.10
3.80    2.12
3.82    2.13
3.84    2.14
3.86    2.15
3.88    2.16
3.90    2.18
3.92    2.19
3.94    2.20
3.96    2.21
3.98    2.22
4.00    2.23
4.02    2.25
4.04    2.26
4.06    2.27
4.08    2.28
4.10    2.29
4.12    2.30
4.14    2.32
4.16    2.33
4.18    2.34
4.20    2.35
4.22    2.36
4.24    2.37
4.26    2.39
4.28    2.40
4.30    2.41
4.32    2.42
4.34    2.43
4.36    2.44
4.38    2.46
4.40    2.47
4.42    2.48
4.44    2.49
4.46    2.50
4.48    2.51
4.50    2.52
4.52    2.54
4.54    2.55
4.56    2.56
4.58    2.57
4.60    2.58
4.62    2.59
4.64    2.61
4.66    2.62
4.68    2.63
4.70    2.64
4.72    2.65
4.74    2.66
4.76    2.68
4.78    2.69
4.80    2.70
4.82    2.71
4.84    2.72
4.86    2.73
4.88    2.74
4.90    2.76
4.92    2.77
4.94    2.78
4.96    2.79
4.98    2.80
5.00    2.81
5.02    2.83
5.04    2.84
5.06    2.85
5.08    2.86
5.10    2.87
5.12    2.88
5.14    2.89
5.16    2.91
5.18    2.92
5.20    2.93
5.22    2.94
5.24    2.95
5.26    2.96
5.28    2.97
5.30    2.99
5.32    3.00
5.34    3.01
5.36    3.02
5.38    3.03
5.40    3.04
5.42    3.06
5.44    3.07
5.46    3.08
5.48    3.09
5.50    3.10
5.52    3.11
5.54    3.12
5.56    3.14
5.58    3.15
5.60    3.16
5.62    3.17
5.64    3.18
5.66    3.19
5.68    3.20
5.70    3.22
5.72    3.23
5.74    3.24
5.76    3.25
5.78    3.26
5.80    3.27
5.82    3.28
5.84    3.30
5.86    3.31
5.88    3.32
5.90    3.33
5.92    3.34
5.94    3.35
5.96    3.37
5.98    3.38
6.00    3.39
6.02    3.40
6.04    3.41
6.06    3.42
6.08    3.43
6.10    3.45
6.12    3.46
6.14    3.47
6.16    3.48
6.18    3.49
6.20    3.50
6.22    3.51
6.24    3.53
6.26    3.54
6.28    3.55
6.30    3.56
6.32    3.57
6.34    3.58
6.36    3.59
6.38    3.61
6.40    3.62
6.42    3.63
6.44    3.64
6.46    3.65
6.48    3.66
6.50    3.67
6.52    3.69
6.54    3.70
6.56    3.71
6.58    3.72
6.60    3.73
6.62    3.74
6.64    3.75
6.66    3.77
6.68    3.78
6.70    3.79
6.72    3.80
6.74    3.81
6.76    3.82
6.78    3.83
6.80    3.85
6.82    3.86
6.84    3.87
6.86    3.88
6.88    3.89
6.90    3.90
6.92    3.91
6.94    3.93
6.96    3.94
6.98    3.95
7.00    3.96
```

Comment: `y_test` is probably in a random order. Might need to sort the array before plotting.

Comment: In `plt.plot(X_test, y_pred, ...)` you need to sort both arrays. Something like `x_order = np.argsort(X_test)` and then `plt.plot(X_test[x_order], y_pred[x_order], ...)`

Comment: @JohanC Thanks, it worked! However, I'm tryna get a best fit line from `X_test` and `y_pred` instead of connecting them via a line.

Comment: `import seaborn as sns` and then `sns.regplot(x=X_test, y=y_pred)`

Comment: @JohanC Thanks for the function! I was looking for a non linear best fit line and `sns.regplot` is able to do it!